# Image resizing problem for a vtkActor2D holding a vtkImageData

Tags: vtk

I have converted a C# Bitmap to unsigned char array and was able to let the image show up using the following code:

```
void VTKCaller::Render2DImage(unsigned char * iImageBytes, int iWidth, int iHeight, int iBytesPerPixel, int iStrideSize)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
    imageData->SetDimensions(iWidth, iHeight, 1);
    imageData->SetOrigin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    imageData->SetSpacing(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    imageData->AllocateScalars(VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR, iBytesPerPixel);
    // Some loops here ...
        imageData->SetScalarComponentFromFloat(...);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapper> imageMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapper>::New();
    imageMapper->SetInputData(imageData);
    imageMapper->SetColorWindow(255); // width of the color range to map to
    imageMapper->SetColorLevel(127.5); // center of the color range to map to

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor2D> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor2D>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(imageMapper);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddActor(actor);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renWin = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renWin);

    renWin->Render();
    renderWindowInteractor->Start();
}
```

But the image won't resize. I tried to actor->SetWidth or SetHeight and it does not work. Please advise. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to resize an image (from the VTK example):

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageResize> resize =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageResize>::New();  
resize->SetInputData(imageData);
resize->SetOutputDimensions(newSizeX, newSizeY, 1);
resize->Update();
```

And I'm **not sure** if you still have to flag the actor as modified so that it refreshes the output:

```
actor->Modified();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We decided to change the image size instead. But fixed-size 2D actors will have magnify problems. Hahaha. Anyways. Thanks so much.